# Prevent applying Jquery to one particular select dropdown element

Tags: jquery, select

I am applying the custom Jquery to all my select dropdown in the whole site.but for one select dropdown.I don't want this select Jquery to apply.

please help me.

Comment: Share the JQuery and some sample select tags you are trying to apply the JQuery to along with the select tag you don't want to apply it to.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the jQuery :not function?

```
$('select:not(.normal_select)').customJqueryFunction();
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Ha. I didn't know you can use it as `:not`. I only new the `.not` approach. I guess I learn new things every day. +1.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you do this:

```
jQuery('select').doSomething();
```

You can add to your select a certain class let's say 'no-transform'.
Then you can call it like this:

```
jQuery('select').not('.no-transform').doSomething();
```